# Avoid a URL cached in browser temporary files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to avoid a URL being cached in the browser's temporary files.

For example,

```
<object width="640" height="480">
     <param name=,"movie" value="http://mywebpage/wmvFlightPass.wmv" />
     <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
     <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
     <param name="autostart" value="true">
     <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
     <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
     <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
     <param name="no-cache" value="true">
     <embed src="http://mywebpage/wmvFlightPass.wmv" width="640" height="480" />
     </embed>
  </object>
```

I have a URL (http://mywebpage/wmvFlightPass.wmv) that is opened in an  tag in asp.net. I don't want this html file to be stored in the browser's cache.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused (a *.wmv file does not contain HTML, for one thing). Do you want to prevent caching of the URL string, or the contents of the file that the URL refers to?

Comment: I'm prevent caching of the URL string...........

Comment: Your terminology is way off, and is making it very difficult to understand what you really want. Browsers do not "cache URL strings". Do you want to prevent the WMV file from being cached, or keep the WMV file URL out of the history, or force the WMV file to be loaded fresh every time?

Comment: You can't prevent caching of *just* the URL string; you can only prevent caching of the entire page on which the string is present. @Robert's answer below will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can add a meta tag on the overall HTML file

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

The data inside the .wmv file won't be cached as you've added a no-cache parameter and that data should be static anyway?

Comment: Does Pragma really do anything anymore? It was deprecated in HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score -2):

Add a unique time parameters to the url, for example `http://mywebpage/wmvFlightPass.wmv?t=201112021244`, and the browser will not cache it.

Comment: That's not correct. Query strings do not prevent browser caching.

Comment: They prevent browser caching if they are updated every time with a different value. I suggested to use some kind of current timestamp to achieve this. `http://mywebpage/wmvFlightPass.wmv?t=CURRENTTIMESTAMP`

Comment: it's not correct to say that it prevents caching.  the browser does still cache the item, it just doesn't load it from the cache for a request to a different url, which is what you are accomplishing with using a different querystring paramter every time.  it prevents the browser serving the cached content.  this may or may not answer the intent of the question, which is unclear.

Comment: Not only does this *not* prevent caching - it actually forces (potentially) needless caching of multiple copies, each time it is loaded. That might actually be what the OP wants; the question is not very clear at all.

Comment: Ok, sorry. But as you said, the question is not clear. I see it in this way the first time I read it. Hope he will say us something.